# Fixed Gradient Background for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

How do you add a simple two color gradient as background to a UICollectionView. It should cover the whole background and stay fixed even when scrolling the collection view (horizontally).

All layer based solutions I tried so far had issues regarding not covering the whole screen and covering only the initially visible frame. Bonus points for being animatable and not using images ... ;)

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An easy and fast solution is to set the background color of the UICollectionView to 'clear' and add another UIView with the gradient behind it.

Comment: That worked. But I also had to stretch out view by the status bar frame manually to avoid a black bar on top. It felt a bit like a hack. Not sure if there's a better way to get the "true frame".

Comment: CGRect statusBar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                                                     self.view.frame.origin.y - statusBar.size.height,
                                                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                     self.view.frame.size.height + statusBar.size.height)];